# Blogger conditional tag not working in post body

Tags: html, xml, blogger

In my blogger template I tried one things using blogger conditional tags. I tried to show a div named `media-div` if the post have / contains a tag/label name `media`. But its not working. Why ?

Here's my approach. I tried 2 ways, but not working any of them at all.

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == "item" and data:post.labels any (label => label.name == "Media")'>
    <!-- Content to show if the post has a label named "Media" -->
    <div class="media-div">
        This will show if the post has a label named "Media".
    </div>
</b:if>
```

and second approach.

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == "item"'>
    <b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'>
        <b:if cond='label.name == "Media"'>
            <div class="media-div">
                This will show if the post has a label named "Media".
            </div>
        </b:if>
    </b:loop>
</b:if>
```

Blogger Conditional tags not working.